# Attaching a custom function to amp "on" attribute

Tags: amp-html, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit, amp-bind

```
<select id="gtranslator" on="change:gtranslator.doGTranslate(this)">
  <option value="">Select Language</option>
  <option value="arabic">arabic>
  <option value="english">arabic>
</select>
```

What i want, is to be able to execute the **doGTranslate(this)** function on an amp page. 
Am new to amp, so am trying it out with a project.

Thanks.

Comment: see discussion here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/14794

Comment: Thanks, but i did that before asking, it didn't help